# delegateEvents in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

Can anyone please explain me what delegateEvents in backbone.js does? [The documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) did not help me to understand.

My exact use case is:

I have a main view X with an inner view Y. They work great, but if I go to main view Z and then go back to X (reusing, not recreating) then events attached to Y child elements get lost. delegateEvents solves this but 
I want to understand why.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Essentially, when you call `.remove()` it is a proxy to the jQuery [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function, which removes the element from the DOM, as well as all associated events from the event hash that were bound to the element.

Backbone's View element still contains the `.el`, but upon re-inserting in the DOM, the jQuery element has lost all of it's bound listeners.

There are a few solutions:

1. Completely destroy the view element, including unbinding all model/controller events with the new [destroy](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/1353) method (currently only in the github, it will be added in the next release of Backbone) and create a new view when coming back (rather than just caching and re-rendering) - my preferred method
2. Create a method (or extend remove) to use jQuery's [detatch](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) which apparently does the same as remove without losing the event bindings - haven't done it but seems like it would work
3. Call `.delegateEvents()` in every render - what you're currently doing now

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 13):

delegateEvents takes the `events: { ... }` declaration for your view instance, and binds the specified events to the specified DOM elements, with the specified callback methods to handle the events.

So, a DOM tree that looks like this after being rendered:

```
<div> 
  <a href="#" id="foo">foo</a>
</div>
```

And a view defined like this:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "click .foo": "fooClicked"
  },

  fooClicked: function(e){
    // handle the click, here
  },

  render: function(){
    // render the specified HTML, here
  }
});
```

will properly handle clicking the "foo" link, so that you can respond to the click in your code.

The breakdown of the `events` declaration is: `"eventname selector": "callback"` where "eventname" is any DOM event, such as "click". "selector" is any valid jQuery selector, which is run against your view's `el` for the DOM element to bind the event to. "callback" is the name of the method on this view to call, when the event for that DOM element fires.

hope that helps

Comment: thanks - but why do I need to call it explicitly when I return to an already created view? everything was already bind on the first time

Comment: this post explains that in detail: http://tbranyen.com/post/missing-jquery-events-while-rendering ... due to this, and a few other issues, i consider view re-use an anti-pattern. don't re-use them. re-create them.

Comment: Thank you! Your brief explanation resolved the mystery of this function in my mind.